# Booting from CF

Tags: hard-disk, boot, linux

I have an older computer and want to install Linux on it.
I want to do this on a CF card. I have tried many things, but get a WRITE ERROR.
I get the write error when I try to install Linux ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386.
I think this happens when it wants to start unpacking.
I have also tried versions of Linux mint, same result.
When I boot the computer with the IDE adapter for CF card I get no errors but end up with a black screen with a blinking line. ( example _ ).
For the IDE adapter for CF card I can take a picture if necessary, but I can already tell you that there is only one red light on it.
I have tried 2 CF card `s 1x 8G and 1x 4G.

I have already supplied the CF card with the extensive MS Dos files (which are normally on the boot diskette).
I have found on the internet how to copy MS Dos files that are normally on a boot floppy to CF card
This should make it possible to boot from CF card.
I can tell that the CF card is recognized in the bios. It shows the name, the size in MB.
I also see during booting Fixed Disk 0:sdcfxs-8g ( this is in the beging )
Also I see during booting that my light of HHD and also on the CF card adapter blink red once .
I have searched a lot on the internet but am now stuck.
Computer
Pentium III 1GHz:
here's the full specs:

Inwin L545 mATX case

Powerman 240 Watt PSU

Asus CUSL2-M

Pentium III 1Ghz

512MB PC133

Leadtek Winfast Geforce2 Pro

Turtle Beach Montego II

Intel Pro/100+ Nic

Pioneer DVD-104S Slot Load

CF card 8G

bios version A09

I looked at this site, but I didn't feel like there were any similar questions among them.
I'll make sure to let you know the bios version yet.
Since I don't have a floppy drive in this computer
, I am looking for a way without one, if possible.
I have also tried formatting the CF card as NTFS and FAT ( With a USB card reader via another computer  ) but it still doesn't work.
I have also read this answer

[Cannot boot from a Compact Flash card](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5825/cannot-boot-from-a-compact-flash-card)

Is there anyone who can help me further, thanks in advance.

Here's the boot-time error:

[image: Error message shown at boot]

Comment: WRITE ERROR from what? You found what ‘this’ on the Internet? Care to provide some screenshots?

Comment: Additional information would be useful for us to answer this question: motherboard model number, or laptop model.

Comment: Is the CF card adapter you're using an IDE-CF adapter, or a USB-CF adapter? Support for booting USB devices was fairly new in the Pentium III era, and may not be present in your motherboard's BIOS.

Comment: @Kaz I would presume it’s an IDE adapter (given that it’s apparently visible at POST time), but yes, it would be nice to have it clarified too.

Comment: Somehow it’s even more of a mess than before: one time you talk about copying MS-DOS files and getting a blank screen, then you show a kernel panic message. Though one thing is clear now at least: ‘write error’ when unpacking the initramfs means there is not enough RAM. Try something lighter-weight.

Comment: +1 for what @user3840170 said.  Something like Lubuntu or LXLE should work with 512MB RAM (standard Ubuntu won't).  [See here](https://www.techradar.com/news/best-lightweight-linux-distro) for some other options.

Comment: From the screenshot of the Linux boot error, the motherboard appears to be from a Dell Dimension L600CX. This model's motherboard uses an intel 810e chipset, per documentation at https://www.dell.com/community/Desktops-General-Read-Only/dimension-L600CX/td-p/3683541 . It does not support booting from USB devices.

Comment: That's right, I tried it out on 2 computers and had taken a picture of the Dell and I don't have a picture of the other. Didn't pay attention and posted the wrong picture.Sorry.

Comment: This looks like two questions: The first one is about trying to boot a Linux installer (from CD?), getting a "write/error". The second one is about trying to boot DOS from a CF card, which seems to crash. Please don't mix them.